# Iterating through a new type in Ocaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

So I have defined my own type as such:

```
type test = Empty
| Int of int
| Str of string
| List of test list;;
```

I am trying to iterate through the list and evaluate each head but I can't seem to make it work.

```
type evalRes = Next /* | other matches just ignore this. It's needed for something else */;;
let rec eval (test:test) : (evalRes) = match test with
| Int i -> /* do int stuff */; Next
| Str s ->  /* string stuff */; Next
| List(stmt1::tail) -> eval stmt1;;
```

I know that will only evaluate the first one. How can I get it to evaluate the rest of the list? And my type test is going to have more cases to match on, this is just a basic test.

Answer (score 0):

The `tail` has type `test list`, that means that you need some function that can accept `test list`. A good start would be to look at `List.map` and `List.fold`. And of course, in that case you even don't need to deconstruct list. The hard part is to decide how to merge the results of each statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to apply `eval` recursively on `tail`, you need to turn it back into a `test`. This can be achieved by:

```
let rec eval (test:test) : evalRes = match test with
| Int i -> /* do int stuff */; Next
| Str s ->  /* string stuff */; Next
| List(stmt1::tail) -> (eval stmt1) ++ (eval (List tail))
```

Obviously, as suggested by ivg, using `List.fold` seems more appropriate in that case:

```
let rec eval (test:test) : evalRes = match test with
| Int i  -> /* do int stuff */; Next
| Str s  -> /* string stuff */; Next
| List l -> List.fold_left (fun res test -> res ++ (eval test)) Next l
```

Where `(++)` is the way you would handle the sequence of `evalRes`.

```
let (++) a b = b
```

(Probably something more interesting than that).